# Stuck on No_Frills_Magento_layout section 2.4

Tags: php, xml, magento, zend-framework, mage

I have been following this guide fairly successfully up to this point
here is the code I am working with:

```
public function complexAction()
        {
            $layout= Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
            $path = Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Nofrills_Booklayout') . DS . 'page-layouts' . DS . 'complex.xml';
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($path, Mage::getConfig()->getModelClassName('core/layout_element'));
            $layout->setXml($xml);
            $layout->generateBlocks();
            echo $layout->setDirectOutput(true)->getOutput();
        }                   
    }
```

After loading the corresponding url all I get is a white screen.
I var_dumped $path and $Xml and both seem to display the right info. but when I do the same with:

```
$layout->setDirectOutput(true)->getOutput();
```

I get:

```
string(0) ""
```

Any advice will be helpful.

original code from complex.xml

```
<layout>    
    <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="root" template="simple-page/2col.phtml" output="toHtml">
        <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="additional_head" template="simple-page/head.phtml" />

        <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="sidebar">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>simple-page/sidebar.phtml</template></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" />
    </block>    
</layout>
```

Comment: Could you clarify which URL you're accessing?

Comment: Here is the url I am trying to access: http://m.healthandmed.com/nofrills_booklayout/update/complex

Comment: Looks like it's var_dumping an empty string.  I would confirm there's no debugging code in the included files.

Comment: Check this answer for a better way to render layouts:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/what-is-required-to-make-this-renderlayout-work

Comment: @AlexAguilar If you (temporarily) replace the contents of `complex.xml` with the XML string you were using in previous examples, does that render anything?

Comment: @AlanStorm Yes that worked. Why did the original block of code not work? Also, Thank you for teaching me how to Magento. Your free tutorials and book have taught me a lot.

Comment: @AlexAguilar Could you post the contents of your complex.xml as a code sample above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so based on your comments above, it sounds like `getOutput` returns an empty string, and that the blank white screen isn't a hidden PHP error, it's the result of Magento/PHP not rendering anything for the layout.

First debugging step: Make sure you're loading the `complex.xml` you think you are.  The following should echo back the contents of the file

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); //tell the browser not to render HTML
echo $xml->asXml();
echo "\nDone\n";
```

Assuming you see the same XML that's in the file, move on to the next steps.

The following layout XML (in `complex.xml`)

```
<layout>    
    <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="root" template="simple-page/2col.phtml" output="toHtml">
        <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="additional_head" template="simple-page/head.phtml" />

        <block type="nofrills_booklayout/template" name="sidebar">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>simple-page/sidebar.phtml</template></action>
        </block>

        <block type="core/text_list" name="content" />
    </block>    
</layout>
```

should

- Instantiate a `nofrills_booklayout/template` block
- Set that block's template to `simple-page/2col.phtml`
- Render that template `simple-page/2col.phtml`

The `simple-page/2col.phtml` template contains the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <?php echo $this->getChildhtml('additional_head'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->getChildhtml('sidebar'); ?>
    <section>
    <?php echo $this->getChildhtml('content'); ?>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

So, since your code renders an empty string vs. a blank page with an HTML skeleton, that tells me Magento/PHP never get to `2col.phtml`.  I would

- Make sure the "Allow Symlinks" is set to yes in the backend.  Despite its label, this feature actually means "don't let people render phtml files outside of `app/design`, and the No Frills modules mess with this a little so you don't need to stress about `app/design` until you're ready.   You've gotten this far in the book, so I don't think that's a problem, but it's worth checking
- Make sure your current module code has a `simple-page/2col.phtml`
- Try creating a template block directly in PHP -- does this work?

.

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')
    ->createBlock('nofrills_booklayout/template')
    ->setTemplate('simple-page/2col.phtml');

var_dump($block->toHtml());
```

My guess is your `simple-page/2col.phtml` is missing, or PHP can't load it for some reasons. Hopefully the above gets you on the right track.  Feel free to [get in touch via support](http://www.pulsestorm.net/contact-us) if you need additional assistance.

Comment: The issue was solved after changing "Allow Symlinks" to yes. Thank for your help getting this issue solved. I hope it helps others who get stuck.